# Does sqlcmd by default wait for execution of a Transact-SQL script file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlcmd

I'm passing the following parameters into sqlcmd on a sql server:

```
string parameter = $"-S {data.DataSource} -d {data.InitialCatalogue} -b -E -I -i \"{file}\"";

CommandRunner.Execute("sqlcmd", parameter);
```

Based on what i've found on MSDN so far, this should not instantly quit once it has started the scripts without further parameters, but is that actually the case? Will it wait for the query in the script to run before exiting?

Sqlcmd is started using the following implementation:

```
public static void Execute(string executable, string commandLineParameters)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Executing {executable} with command line parameters '{commandLineParameters}'...");

            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(executable, commandLineParameters)
                            {
                                UseShellExecute = false,
                                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                                RedirectStandardError = true
                            };

            var process = new Process
                          {
                              StartInfo = startInfo
                          };
            process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
            process.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);

            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();
            process.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine("Exit code execution: " + process.ExitCode);

            if (process.ExitCode != 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("An error exit code was returned!");
            }
        }
```

which in turn is called like this:

```
   foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(scriptPath))
                {
                    if (Path.GetExtension(file) != SQL_FILE_EXTENSION)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    databaseConnector.ExecuteScript(file);
                }
```

Comment: yes, it will wait. but why do you ask?

Comment: I update my database using these scripts, start up my application and successfully connect to the db. But after successfully executing many stored procedures, a single stored procedure i try to execute ~1 minute later never elapses. This happens sporadically and my first guess was that maybe the update scripts are still running at this point.

Comment: Look elsewhere for possible culprits. You can use SSMS Activity Monitor if you are able to repro or SQL profiler to look for reason why the stored procedure call is blocking.

Comment: It looks like you run sqlcmd from a .NET application (possibly using System.Diagnostics.Process) because of the interpolated string. If so, show us that code as well. Maybe sqlcmd keeps on running but your .NET application doesn't wait for it to complete...

Comment: @Christian.K I edited the initial question and added the implementation details.

Comment: You've asked a long detailed large question based in a bad assumption. Your stored procedure might be taking a long time for a lot of reasons, It's unlikely to be because a DDL script isn't finished. If the SP was just created, it might be taking a while to generate the query plan. Use something like `sp_whoisactive` to troubleshoot.